# How to Handle SSL Certificate in karateUI driver?

Tags: karate

When I open my resource, I am faced with notification "Your connection is not private".[image: screen with the notification]
   Is there a way to disable the verification of the server certificate in the browser or specify the desired trusted certificate through configuring the karate driver?
  Please, provide the solution for configuration the driver for overcome this notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is helpful feedback. Can you see if adding this command-line flag helps: `--ignore-certificate-errors`.

Refer `addOptions` in the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#configure-driver

Else it would be great if you provide a way to replicate and submit an issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

This will also work for other chrome options such as `--disable-notifications`.

Please also see these threads:

a) https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1134#issuecomment-638990087
b) https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1228

Comment: Thank you, your recommendation helped. I added: configure driver = {type: 'chrome',addOptions:['--ignore-certificate-errors']} .